# I have problem when i try create a project with rails new blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is the Error i got i edit Gemfile but keep saying that error idk why i install all gem and requirements

**Error :**

```
rails aborted!
TZInfo::DataSourceNotFound: tzinfo-data is not present. Please add gem 'tzinfo-data' to your Gemfile and run bundle install
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/ruby/website/store/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/ruby/website/store/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/ruby/website/store/bin/spring:10:in `require'
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/ruby/website/store/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/ruby/website/store/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'

Caused by:
TZInfo::DataSources::ZoneinfoDirectoryNotFound: None of the paths included in TZInfo::DataSources::ZoneinfoDataSource.search_path are valid zoneinfo directories.
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/ruby/website/store/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/ruby/website/store/bin/rails:5:in `<top (required)>'
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/ruby/website/store/bin/spring:10:in `require'
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/ruby/website/store/bin/spring:10:in `block in <top (required)>'
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/ruby/website/store/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => app:template => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Looks like you’re using spring. Try “bin/spring stop”

Comment: just type ( bin/spring stop )  in terminal ?

Comment: just checking... you did run `bundle` after editing the Gemfile, right? You didn't mention it, so I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: error says to do this -> `Please add gem 'tzinfo-data' to your Gemfile and run bundle install`

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: i edit Gemfile and i also run it but still same error

Comment: i do all of things idk why show that error

Answer (score 9):

Go to that file in console and type `code .`it will open vscode or u can open ur file on any code editor. Then from the Gemfile remove `gem "tzinfo-data", platforms: %i[x64_mingw]` line and add `gem 'tzinfo-data'` and `gem 'tzifo'` & save the changes.
after that on console write `bundler update`. **NOW YOU ARE GOOD TO GO**

Comment: Should be `gem 'tzinfo'`. Says the edit suggestion queue is full.